# Efficient generation of chi random variables

Tags: random-generation, c++, chi-distribution, fortran

I need to generate random variables generated from a chi distribution (**not** chi-squared!).  There doesn't seem to be standard mechanism in C++ in (for example) [Boost::Random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html#boost_random.reference.distributions) and hence I am looking for an alternative implementation implemented in C++ (or an easily compatible language such as C or FORTRAN).

There is one paper in [ACM TOMS](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=328512.328522) on the topic. Or, should I simply take the square root of a chi-squared random variable, of which there are several implementations?

Which is likely to be fastest - unfortunately, I need to draw a lot of them.

---

**Update:**

In response to the below comments, these are some notes for my specific application:

- I am looking for a C/C++ compatible implementation, or sufficient detail to program one myself.
- The application is CPU sensitive, and is run on a modest embedded platform (400MHz with a scalar double FPU and limited cache, but no sqrt(), sin(), exp() or similar instructions). Since actual run-time is not easy to predict *a priori*, I am looking for algorithms that are *amongst* the fastest and known to perform well. I can evaluate each of these on my own hardware.
- I already have facilities for generating uniform and normal random numbers. I can get chi-squared if necessary.
- DoF is always an integer, usually between 15 and 39.

The answer I accept will have the following content:

- Which methods are considered "fast", and how are they implemented?
- Do they otherwise have known disadvantages (e.g. numerical stability)?
- Are there any methods that should be specifically avoided?

Comment: Moderators: can I suggest a new tag of chi or chi-distribution? I don't yet have enough reputation to create it.

Comment: Done (I'm not a mod, but you don't need one for that)

Comment: Do you need variable degrees of freedom, or just one particular one? If it was one particular one, something like a carefully implemented ziggurat like method might be about as fast as you'd get. (How many is a lot?)

Comment: @Glen_b, multiple degrees of freedom. I've actually misread the number that I need... I only need in the order of thousands per second, albeit on an embedded system. Nevertheless, if the internal implementation avoid transcendental functions, that would be preferred.

Comment: I just did it the "slow" way in R - which is already regarded as being slow. That is, (i) I started with n randomly generated degrees of freedom (so there's no possible speedup in adapting to a specific distribution), and then (ii) generated n chisquared random variables each with its own previously obtained df, then took the square root. For n = 10^5, it did the second stage (generating chi-squares taking square roots & assigning the result) in <0.1s on my slow little laptop. You should be able to do much better (maybe 10-20x?) on a better machine in C++ even doing it the 'dumb-but-easy' way.

Comment: That is, I'd be astonished if you couldn't do 10^6 chi random variables the dumb way in well under a second, or 10^4 in well under a hundredth of a second. Why would you bother with being "smart" in this case?

Comment: The target is a 400Mhz processor with a basic CPU and Limited cache. Unlike x86 it does not have hardware sin cos or exp. Suffice to say that even 0.5% is valuable to me and thus the original question stands.

Comment: You should probably add those conditions to your Q, and then since you want not just 'reasonably fast', but 'the fastest'... (but without a full specification of the relative speeds of all the operations), so my response would be 'uh, that's a decent research problem, have you got say 50K and a few months?' :)

Comment: My general advice would be to write special code to handle small df (especially if its integer df), and then consider whether you can beat whichever is faster out of a ratio-of-uniforms approach or just using an asymmetric table mountain proposal for an accept-reject.

Comment: I have updated the scope of the question to reflect the comments in this discussion.

Comment: "*Which methods are considered "fast", and how are they implemented?*" -- sampling chi-distributions is pretty esoteric, and when you add in your restrictions, there's unlikely to be *any* consensus about what's 'fast'. You're assuming a literature that doesn't exist. We can make suggestions about what should be good approaches in general, but as for what's fast on your machine, as I have already explained, that likely depends on things we don't know, like the relative speed with which you *can* implement various calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a pure C implementation that generates a little over three million samples per second (using df=20) on my machine (Macbook Pro i7 @ 2.7 GHz).

I've assumed the only mathematical functions supported natively are multiplication, division, addition, subtraction, and the rand() function from the standard library. You can easily replace the rand() function with something equivalent - it seems to be the bottleneck in this program after profiling. I've avoided linking to math.h to avoid pulling in the extra code.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const int HALF_RAND_MAX = RAND_MAX/2;
const float c1 = -3.0/2;
const float c2 = 11.0/6;
const float c3 = -25.0/12;
const float c4 = 137.0/60;
const float c5 = -49.0/20;

// Reuse of the other squared random normal.
static int hasSpare = 0;
static float spare = 0.0;

float randu() {
  // Generates a random float uniformly between [-1.0, 1.0) using RAND_MAX
  return ((float)rand())/(HALF_RAND_MAX) - 1;
}

inline float lnxinvx(float x) {
  // return approximation for ln(x) / x
  float v = x - 1;
  return v + v*(c1 + v*(c2 + v*(c3 + v*(c4 + v*c5))));
}
float fast_sqrt(float x) {
  // Adapted from Carmac's famous Q_sqrt trick.
  int i;
  float xhalf = x*0.5f;
  i = *(int*)&x;
  i = 0x5f3759df - (i >> 1);
  x = *(float*)&i;
  x = x*(1.5f - (xhalf * x * x));
  x = x*(1.5f - (xhalf * x * x));
  return 1.0f/x;
}

float squared_random_normal() {
  // Generate a squared random normal variable, or use the spare one.
  if (hasSpare) {
    hasSpare = 0;
    return spare;
  } else {
    float u = randu();
    float v = randu();
    float s = u*u + v*v;
    while (s >= 1) {
      u = randu();
      v = randu();
      s = u*u + v*v;
    }
    float mul = -2.0*lnxinvx(s);
    spare = v * v * mul;
    hasSpare = 1;
    return u * u * mul;
  }
}

float rand_chi(unsigned int df) {
  // Add up "df" squared random normals and take the square root.
  float acc = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for(i; i < df; ++i) {
    acc += squared_random_normal();
  }
  return fast_sqrt(acc);
}

int main(char* argc, char** argv) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int i;
  int df = atoi(argv[1]);
  int n = atoi(argv[2]);
  printf("Using %i degrees of freedom\n", df);
  printf("Generating %i samples\n", n);
  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    //printf("Next variate: %f\n", rand_chi(df));
    rand_chi(df);
  }
}
```

And here's the timing information, for 20 degrees of freedom.

```
Wed Aug 14 00:08:04 ~/Dropbox/RandomCodeSnippets/chidist $ gcc -O3 -funroll-loops -fwhole-program chidist.c -o chidist
Wed Aug 14 00:08:09 ~/Dropbox/RandomCodeSnippets/chidist $ time ./chidist 20 10000000
Using 20 degrees of freedom
Generating 10000000 samples

real    0m3.208s
user    0m3.205s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Hopefully this is roughly what you were looking for (or is roughly fast enough).

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting implementation as a sum of normals. I would replace the series in lnxinvx by its [Horner form](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HornerForm.html) for stability, but it looks quite worthwhile.

Comment: I've made some other optimizations that get about 50% improvement. Updating the post now for more details - clever thought about the horner form, too!

Comment: Looks like I managed to squeeze out a 3x improvement.

Answer (score 0):

To generate Chi distribution random variate in `Mathematica`, general expression is

```
RandomVariate[ChiDistribution[degree of freedom], number of random variates]
```

For example we have to generate five random variates with three degree of freedom the code is

```
RandomVariate[ChiDistribution[3],5]
```

The output is

```
{0.753102, 1.6647, 1.25129, 0.456877, 0.632508}
```

Comment: @Glen_b Than `C++` tag should be added in question. I read "an alternative implementation".

Comment: Good points; OP should at least clarify whether an algorithm he could implement in C++ is required or if he's looking for something other than C++, which I agree is a possible way to read the post.

Comment: Agreed, clarified - target implementation is for C++

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet used [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code.html) package but you may look into it. This package is useful if C++ has been decided as the language of choice.